# Problems with TVideoImage

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, timage

I'm problems with TvideoImage, I use to capture image from webCam. I have a Timage and I set using `fVideoImage.setDisplayCanvas(imgCamera.canvas)`, the first runs cool, but when I try open again, no longer works. The Image is white.

```
my code is:
on create:

       fVideoImage := TVideoImage.Create;
       bActivated := False;

       DeviceList := TStringList.Create;
       fVideoImage.GetListOfDevices(DeviceList);
       cbListaCameras.Items := DeviceList;
       DeviceList.Free;

    on power button is:

     procedure TFormCamera.btnLigarClick(Sender: TObject);
     var
       camDevice: string;
     begin
       try
          if not(bActivated)then
          begin
             camDevice := trim(cbListaCameras.Items.Strings[cbListaCameras.ItemIndex]);
             if(camDevice = '')then
             begin
                ShowMessage('Atenção, informe o dispositivo!');
                cbListaCameras.SetFocus;
                Exit;
             end;

             fVideoImage.SetDisplayCanvas(imgCamera.Canvas);
             fVideoImage.VideoStart(camDevice);
             bActivated := True;

             lblCameraStatus.Caption := 'Ligada';
             lblCameraStatus.Font.Color := clGreen;

          end
          else
             MessageDlg('Atenção, camera já está ligada!', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);>>

       except
          bActivated := False;
          lblCameraStatus.Caption := 'Desligada';
          lblCameraStatus.Font.Color := clRed;
          ShowMessage('Atenção, erro ao tentar ligar a camera!');
       end;
    end;
    On close button is:

       fVideoImage.VideoStop;
       bActivated := false;
       imgCamera.Picture := nil;
       //imgCamera.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(nil);
       Close;
```

The Image is white. Even when i give free at all, i don't know because it occurs, please help me.

Comment: What is `TVideoImage`?

Comment: is a class of VFrames

Comment: Please don't let this become a game of twenty questions

Comment: is a unit of the DirectX component

Comment: What DirectX component?  Come on now - we need the full information.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Vframes unit is known as a directx wrapper used to interface with webcams.

Comment: @whosrdaddy What I really want is for the asker to realise the importance of stating all these facts. I think I failed.